# Applescript QuickTime pro save export settings

Tags: macos, export, applescript, quicktime

I am trying to save export setting of Quicktime movie to a file using AppleScript. This is my code:

```
set file2save to (choose file name default location (path to desktop) default name "setting.qtes")

tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    tell document "video.mov"
        save export settings for QuickTime movie to file2save
    end tell
end tell
```

But I get error `"QuickTime Player 7 got an error: An error of type -2107 has occurred." number -2107`
This error occurs on the "save export settings" line...
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell the problem is that functions is no longer supported can't find anything regarding it in the dictionary

still wasn't working for me but I found[this thread](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=5623) which looks like it may help

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have QuickTime Pro? I checked the dictionary and it's there...

Comment: 1'm not 100% sure I do NOT have pro but I don't think that matters, but I could be wrong; i do get the same error you do when I run your code Could you take a screen shot of the dictionary for me so I can see what you are seeing ?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I have updated my question with the screenshot.

Comment: Quicktime Player was completely rewritten for snow leopard, and has a much shorter (i.e. less interesting) dictionary. You can still download the old player from apple (called "Quicktime Player 7") and it has the export commands.I know many of you know this, but some obviously don't.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You can see that I got the doc name from Quicktime to make sure it was correct, so your problem is with the document name. Note that if the movie is frontmost then you can also use terms like "tell first document".

```
set file2save to (choose file name default location (path to desktop) default name "setting.qtes")

tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    set docName to name of first document
    tell document docName
        save export settings for QuickTime movie to file2save
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't work for me. I still get error -2107. What version of QuickTime 7 are you running? I am on 7.6.6.

Comment: Quicktime 7.6.6. MacOSX 10.6.7. Note that the movie must be open and if you reference it by name make sure the name is correct. The description of your error code is: invalidAtomContainerErr, so maybe you'v setup your export options wrong. Start an export and after it starts just stop the export. Then try the script again.

Comment: Another thought... is it a quicktime movie you're getting the export setting for or something else?

Comment: To save export settings, you have to perform one export manually first, then run the script to create the export settings file.